# Multi colors richtextbox save rtf in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, richtextbox

I have created a sort of notepad (richtextbox in winform). You choose to format some of the text.
Example format the color of the text. And also background color.

To color the text, I use 
`ColorDialog myDialog = new ColorDialog();
            if (myDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
             Document.SelectionColor = myDialog.Color;`

and on the background, I use

```
ColorDialog myDialog = new ColorDialog();
        if (myDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            Document.SelectionBackColor = myDialog.Color;
```

And saving it to mysql I use

```
 string rtfText = this.Document.Rtf.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

And fetching the data with

```
Document.Rtf = reader["test"].ToString();
```

The problem occurs when I have a word colored in one color, and another word in a background color. When I fetch the information, all the words get the first color.

In the database, I get this record

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
 {\colortbl ;\red255\green128\blue0;}
 \viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\f0\fs20 Lets test this baby out\par
 }
```

Its the first time I ask I question on this forum, but I have learned alot of you guys, so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I don't know about mysql well. You can try copying the `Rtf` of your textbox before saving into mysql database, then try loading it from mysql database and comparing the `Rtf` you saved before with the fetched `Rtf`. They should be the same. Otherwise, you saved your `Rtf` into mysql database wrong and it could be some kind of `special characters related problem`.

Comment: I have tried reading the rtf before inset in to mysql, and what I can see its the same that I get into the database. I´m wondering if there are any limits in rtf with different colors.

Comment: That sounds strange to me. The `RichTextBox` should display the same text (with same format) if it has the same `Rtf`. Your problem is so strange. I can't help.

Comment: Yes, but does Rtf support different colors and background colors on different word in the samt line ?

Comment: Yes, it does. What you see in your `RichTextBox` should be what you see after assigning its `Rtf` to your fetched `rich text` from your mysql database.

Comment: I changed the background color an one word, and the text color on another word. And then I use this command: